# What is the probability two dice show the same values on their second rolls?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> What is the probability two dice, a red one and a white one, show the same values on their second rolls as on their first rolls?

So I first computed the total number of ways of just getting outcomes from two sets of rolls:

$$6^4$$

Now the next step I wanted to perform was to obtain the number of outcomes in which the value obtained on the first roll is obtained on their second rolls:

$$6^2$$

My reasoning for the $6^2$ is that after we get whatever number for the first set of rolls, the second set doesn't matter. But I feel this just may be too high an outcome because the probability would work out to $0.50$

I am not concerned about finding the probability, I am concerned on performing the combinatorial idea so any feedback there would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: $6^2/6^4$ is not 50%.  Otherwise, I think you've got it.

Comment: for real,  you're right.... it's $$\frac{1}{36}$$.

Comment: "Same value on each die on each of two rolls" or "roll two dice twice, the faces are the same on the second roll"? Quite different...

Comment: @vonbrand it is the latter.  That is how they phrased it in the textbook and it took me a moment to decipher what they meant

Comment: In that case, the first roll is completely irrelevant.

Comment: so then I put the importance on the wrong action then?  should it always be considered the last action in this sort of scenario?

Comment: @dc3rd vonbrand's point is that the way you wrote the question indicates you meant the first meaning, while your comment indicates the second meaning.  If you really meant the second, then the question should be edited to reflect that.

Comment: @vonbrand,BarrySmith: If I'm understanding vonbrand's two alternatives, then neither is the question that was asked.  To me, it seems clear that "two die, a red and a white one, show the same values on their second rolls as on their first rolls" means that the red die shows the same value on its second roll as on its first roll and the white die shows the same value on its second roll as on its first roll.

Comment: @WillOrrick, yay, a third interpretation! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to look at it.  After the first roll of the two dice, you know what you want red to be on the next roll, call it $x$, and you know what white to be, call it $y$.  What is the probability of getting a specific number with a fair die?  So, that is your probability of the second red roll being $x$ and matching the first roll.  Ditto for white.  Assuming that the rolls are independent, multiply these:  $\frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{36}$.  No big numbers were hurt in the filming of this solution.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simply $P(\text{both dice show same number on the first and second rolls}) = \dfrac{6^2}{6^4} = \dfrac{1}{36}$.

Sidenote: say the order didn't matter in which you got the same pairs. For example, $(4,3)$ and $(3,4)$ are the same. What would be the answer in that case?

Comment: Be careful.  $\frac{6^2}{6^4} = \frac{1}{6^2}$.

Comment: If order didn't matter the result could occur in $\frac{1}{36}$ ine way and the exact same the other way,  would it be $\frac{1}{36 * 36}$?

Comment: But some would have only $1$ copy, i.e. $(1,1)$ while others such as $(4,3)$ would have two copies, i.e. $(4,3),(3,4)$. So you must account for that.

Comment: actually I just worked it out.  but the only way I was able to work it out was through writing out all of the cases.  is there a way of avoiding that or in this case the only way to solve it is by writing the cases. This one was symmetric so the cases were able to be reduced,  but that won't always be the case right?

Comment: There are only $6$ cases where we have only $1$ copy: $(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),(6,6)$. So the probability of matching for each of those is  $\dfrac{1}{6^4}$. On the other hand, the probability of matching for each of the other $6^2 - 6 = 30$ cases where there are $2$ copies is $\dfrac{2}{6^4}$. Therefore, the probability here is $6\dfrac{1}{6^4}+30\dfrac{2}{6^4} = \dfrac{11}{216}$.

Comment: @dc3rd Alternate approach to the alternate question.  $(1/6)$th of the time, there is only $1$ way to repeat, because it is doubles.  $(5/6)$th of the time there are $2$ ways to repeat, because it is not doubles.  So, the average number of ways to repeat is $1 + (5/6)$.  So, instead of computing $~\displaystyle \frac{2}{36}~$, you compute $$\frac{1 + \frac{5}{6}}{36}.$$  The point of this comment is **not** the math, but to **stretch** your intuition.